# Setting value for React context values with React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am working on testing a component using react-testing-library.  The component has an alert which accepts a prop that comes from context to determine whether the alert is open or not.

```
const PersonRecord = () => {

  const {
    personSuccessAlert,
    setPersonSuccessAlert,
    updatePersonSuccessAlert,
    setUpdatePersonSuccessAlert,
  } = useContext(PeopleContext);

  return (
      {personSuccessAlert && (
        <div className="person-alert-container">
          <Alert
            ariaLabel="person-create-success-alert"
            icon="success"
            open={personSuccessAlert}
          />
        </div>
      )}
   )
 }
```

So the above code uses context to pull the value of `personSuccessAlert` from `PeopleContext`. If `personSuccessAlert` is true the alert will display. My context file is set up as follows:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const PeopleContext = createContext();

const PeopleContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [personSuccessAlert, setPersonSuccessAlert] = useState(false);
  const [updatePersonSuccessAlert, setUpdatePersonSuccessAlert] = useState(
    false,
  );

  return (
    <PeopleContext.Provider
      value={{
        personSuccessAlert,
        updatePersonSuccessAlert,
        setPersonSuccessAlert,
        setUpdatePersonSuccessAlert,
      }}>
      {children}
    </PeopleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default PeopleContextProvider;
```

Now I am trying to develop a test which passes `personSuccessAlert = true` to the `PersonRecord` component.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
export function renderWithEmptyPerson(
  ui,
  {
    providerProps,
    path = '/',
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
  },
) {
  return {
    ...render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={getEmptyPerson} addTypename={false}>
        <PeopleContextProvider {...providerProps}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Route path={path} component={ui} />
          </Router>
        </PeopleContextProvider>
      </MockedProvider>,
    ),
  };
}

describe('empty person record rendering', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  test('empty person', async () => {

    const providerProps = { value: true };

    const { getByText, queryByText, queryByLabelText } = renderWithEmptyPerson(
      PersonRecord,
      {
        providerProps,
        route: 'people/6d6ed1f4-8294-44de-9855-2999bdf9e3a7',
        path: 'people/:slug',
      },
    );
    expect(getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I have tried different variations of `const providerProps = { value: true };`. Replacing `value` with `personSuccessAlert` did not work.

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `providerProps` to the `PeopleContextProvider`, but the `PeopleContextProvider` is not doing anything with the props. You'll need to actually use those props, for example to set the initial state. You could try something like:

```
const PeopleContextProvider = ({ children, initialPersonSuccessAlert = false }) => {
  const [personSuccessAlert, setPersonSuccessAlert] = useState(initialPersonSuccessAlert);
  const [updatePersonSuccessAlert, setUpdatePersonSuccessAlert] = useState(
    false,
  );

  return (
    <PeopleContext.Provider
      value={{
        personSuccessAlert,
        updatePersonSuccessAlert,
        setPersonSuccessAlert,
        setUpdatePersonSuccessAlert,
      }}>
      {children}
    </PeopleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This would allow you to set the initial state of `personSuccessAlert` by passing in a `initialPersonSuccessAlert` prop. You could update your test like so:

```
const providerProps = { initialPersonSuccessAlert: true };
```

Alternatively, if you only wanted to make changes in your test file, you could consider updating the renderWithEmptyPerson function to use PeopleContext.Provider directly instead of the PeopleContextProvider component. That will allow you to set the context value however you like.

Comment: Hmm, I think this might work, but it requires my to change my actual code rather than just my tests. I was hoping there is some way to mock out the value of personSuccessAlert just within my testing suite.

Comment: If you're dead-set on not modifying the code, then you could consider updating the `renderWithEmptyPerson` function to use `PeopleContext.Provider` directly instead of the `PeopleContextProvider` component. That will allow you to set the context `value` however you like. There is no other good way of doing it, short of mocking `PeopleContextProvider`, `useContext`, or `useState`, all of which I would *strongly not recommend* as it would make your tests extremely brittle.